# Is there a CMS like Plone but in Grails?

Tags: grails, content-management-system, plone

I really like plone as a CMS, but its base is in Python. I would like to know if there is a CMS that has Grails as a base.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to take a look at Weceem CMS, which is open-source and uses Grails as the foundation.

http://www.weceem.org/weceem/

Answer (score 2):

Wrong comparison.  Python is a language.  Grails is a framwork.

Plone (app) --> Zope (framework) --> Python (language)

? (app) --> Grails (framework) --> Groovy (language)

Don't know too much about Grails but maybe this is what you're looking for...
http://sourceforge.net/projects/gocms/

Probably not in the same league as Plone, but then few CMS's are.

Answer (score 1):

There is also Codice ( http:  //github.com/neodevelop/codice/tree/master ) and Countour-CMS (http:  //www.seo-web-services.co.uk/a/contour-cms ) But none of these are production ready.

You can always integrate PHP packages like Wordpress and Plone into grails via the [PHP plugin](http://grails.org/PHP+Plugin), which uses Quercus.